# Elastic search common mapping type and run aggregation based on type of data

Tags: elasticsearch

we have an elastic search index with following mapping (showing only partial mapping relevant to this question)

```
"instFields": {
            "properties": {
              "_index": {
                "type": "object"
              },
              "fieldValue": {
                "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                },
                "type": "string"
              },
              "sourceFieldId": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            },
            "type": "nested"
          }
```

as you can see `fieldValue` type is `string`: in original data in the database for that `fieldValue` column is stored in a `JSON` type column (in Postgresql). use case is such that when this data is stored `fieldValue` can be valid `JsNumber`, `JsString`,`JsBoolean` (any valid `[JsValue][1]`  now question is that when storing this `fieldValue` in ES - it'll have to be a definite type - so we convert `fieldValue` to `String` while pushing data into ElasticSearch.

Following is a sample data from Elastic search

```
"instFields": [
        {
          "sourceFieldId": 1233,
          "fieldValue": "Demo Logistics LLC"
        },
        {
          "sourceFieldId": 1236,
          "fieldValue": "169451"
        }
      ]
```

this is where it gets interesting where now we want to run various [metrics aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics.html) on `fieldValue` - for e.g. if `sourceFieldId = 1236` then run `[avg][3]` on `fieldValue` - problem is `fieldValue` had to be stored as `string` in ES - due to originally `fieldValue` being `JsValue` type field in the application. what's the best way to create mapping in elastic search such that `fieldValue` can be stored with an appropriate type vs `string` type so various metrics aggregation can be run of `fieldValue` which are of type `long` (though encoded as `string` in ES)

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to achieve this is create different fields in elastic search with all possible `type` of `JsValue` (e.g. `JsNumber`, `JsBoolean`,`JsString` etc). now while indexing - application can derive proper type of `JsValue` field to find out whether it's `JsString`, `JsNumber`, `JsBoolean` etc.

on application side I can decode proper `type` of `fieldValue` being indexed

```
value match{
      case JsString(s) => 
      case JsNumber(n) => 
      case JsBoolean(b)
}
```

now modify mapping in elastic search and add more fields - each with proper type - as shown below

```
"instFields": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "_index": {
                                            "type": "object"
                                        }, 
                                        "fieldBoolean": {
                                            "type": "boolean"
                                        }, 
                                        "fieldDate": {
                                            "fields": {
                                                "raw": {
                                                    "format": "dateOptionalTime", 
                                                    "type": "date"
                                                }
                                            }, 
                                            "format": "dateOptionalTime", 
                                            "type": "date"
                                        }, 
                                        "fieldDouble": {
                                            "fields": {
                                                "raw": {
                                                    "type": "double"
                                                }
                                            }, 
                                            "type": "double"
                                        }, 
                                        "fieldLong": {
                                            "fields": {
                                                "raw": {
                                                    "type": "long"
                                                }
                                            }, 
                                            "type": "long"
                                        }, 
                                        "fieldString": {
                                            "fields": {
                                                "raw": {
                                                    "index": "not_analyzed", 
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            }, 
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }, 
                                        "fieldValue": {
                                            "fields": {
                                                "raw": {
                                                    "index": "not_analyzed", 
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            }, 
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
```

now at the time of indexing

```
value match{
      case JsString(s) => //populate fieldString
      case JsNumber(n) => //populate fieldDouble (there is also fieldLong)
      case JsBoolean(b) //populate fieldBoolean
}
```

this way now `boolean` value is stored in `fieldBoolean`, `number` is stored in `long` etc. now running metrics aggregation becomes a normal business by going against `fieldLong` or `fieldDouble` field (depending on the query use case). notice `fieldValue` field is still there in ES mapping and index as before. Application will continue to convert value to `string` and store it in `fieldValue` as before - this way queries which don't care about types can only query `fieldValue` field in the index.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should have two separate fields, one for the case when the value is a string and one for when it is an instance of a number.

Depending on how you're indexing this data, it can be easy or hard.  However, its a bit strange that you have a fields that could be a string or a number.

Regardless, elasticsearch is not going to be able to do both in a single field